# How can I pass variables to my views in php

Tags: php, templates, scope

I have a class which contains a method to load a view. This works perfect and the page is loaded correctly! The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to figure out a way to pass variables to the view that my method currently tries to load. How can I go by passing variables to the page? Is there a way I can manipulate my current code to make this work? Or am I going in the complete opposite direction?

Controller Class:

```
<?php
    class Controller {

        private $args = array();

        public function view($page, $args = null) {

            if ($args !== null) {
                $this->args = $args;
                extract($this->args);
            }

            $page = VIEWS . $page . '.php';
            $template = $this->getTemplate($page);

            echo $template;
        }

        private function getTemplate($file) {
            ob_start();
            include($file);
            $template = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            return $template;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
    class Page extends Controller {

        public function person($age) {
            $data['age'] = $age;
            $this->view('person', $data);
        }

    }
?>
```

View Contents:

```
</h1>My name is Dennis. My age is: <?php echo $age; ?></h1>
```

The end result is an undefined variable ($age).

Comment: @JosephSilber Building a custom framework. More for learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables which you extract in `view()` are not available in `getTemplate()`. It is a different scope. You should instead extract them in the same method that does the rendering.

Also, what you have there is not an MVC view. It's just a [template](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html). A view in MVC is an instance which is responsible for UI logic. It should be requesting the information, that it needs, from model layer and then, if a response is not simply a HTTP location header, creating the HTML using multiple templates.

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. Thanks for the information about the view vs a template! I'm going to read up on that.

Comment: The call to `extract` is not necessary even, because the data is already available in `$this->args`.

Comment: @Jack , I actually would advise against it. It would add *"must be rendered from within object"* as a hidden requirement.

Comment: Makes sense, though "must be rendered with these global variables sounds equally bad to my ears" :)

Comment: @Jack , well ..  the variables that template uses are not global. Only requirement is that they exist in the scope in which the said template is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
</h1>My name is Dennis. My age is: <?php echo $data['age']; ?></h1>
```

Comment: there is no variable $data in that scope

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to pass down the $args variable to getTemplate, and do the extract method in the getTemplate method

```
private function getTemplate($file, $args = null) {
    if ($args !== null) {
        extract($args);
    }
    ob_start();
    include($file);
    $template = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $template;
}
```

when you include and capture the the output, that php file is executed, so before inclusion all the variables must be present

If you dont want to pass down variables you can use $this->args inside of the template

Answer (score 0):

You extract the variables in a different method than where you include the template. If you want to use plain variables in your templates, make sure that they are extracted in the same scope.